# Error in Angular 11 - trying to get data from the back and implement it on the screen - Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to receive the data from the backend/api and trying to render it using *ngFor, but it gives the following errors.

> Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

[image: Errors]

then you have the component, service codes and the authorization method
code contas.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ContaBancaria } from 'src/app/models/conta-bancaria';
import { ContaBancariaService } from './services/contas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contas',
  templateUrl:'./contas.component.html'
})
export class ContasComponent implements OnInit {
  closeResult = '';

  public contasBancarias: ContaBancaria[];
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private contaBancariaService: ContaBancariaService) {}


  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.contaBancariaService.obterTodos()
      .subscribe(
        contasBancarias => this.contasBancarias = contasBancarias,
        error => this.errorMessage);
        console.log(this.contasBancarias.values);
  }

}
```

now code in contas.service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";

import { BaseService } from 'src/app/services/base.service';
import { ContaBancaria } from '../../../../models/conta-bancaria';
//import { CepConsulta, Endereco } from '../models/endereco';

@Injectable()
export class ContaBancariaService extends BaseService {

    contaBancaria: ContaBancaria = new ContaBancaria();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { super() }

    obterTodos(): Observable<ContaBancaria[]> {
        return this.http
            .get<ContaBancaria[]>(this.apiUrlRestrita + "/contasbancarias", super.ObterAuthHeaderJson())
            .pipe(
                catchError(super.serviceError));
                
    }
}
```

```
protected ObterAuthHeaderJson() {
        return {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.LocalStorage.obterTokenUsuario()}`
            })
        };
    }
```

EDIT:
Below is the image of expected JSON/data from the API

[image: json]

Comment: First contasBancarias is array type and you cannot get .value without iterating. Second are you sure you are getting data from backend?

Comment: i am receiving undefined, trying with console.log(contasBancarias)

here's what i should get back

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "agencia": "string",
      "dataUltimaAlteracao": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "desativada": true,
      "descricao": "string",
      "idContaBancaria": 0,
      "loja": {
        "central": true,
        "certificadoTef": "string",
       ....
```

Comment: That means you are getting no value from backend

Comment: would the error be in one of these codes?

Comment: Yes. But you can verify by hitting apis in postman

Answer (score 0):

i think you just have to try this

```
this.contaBancariaService.obterTodos()
      .subscribe(
        contasBancarias => {this.contasBancarias = contasBancarias
 console.log(this.contasBancarias ? this.contasBancarias.values: "not found");
},
        error => this.errorMessage);
       
  }
```

you want to show data after api call but in this case your console statment run first because api take time to complete

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying hthe subscribe to this:

```
 ngOnInit(): void{
    this.contaBancariaService.obterTodos()
      .subscribe(
        (v) => {
          this.contasBancarias = v["data"]
          console.log(this.contasBancarias)
        } 
      )
  }
```

Thanks all for your help! <3